# Setup Multi InputField in Unity 5

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine, user-input

Currently, I have my code working correctly with one InputField (pressure) but I now trying to setup a second InputField to display the drillpipe input.  How do I add another inputfield (ex. drillpipe) to my current script?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour {

        InputField input;

        int intPressure = 0;
        int drillpipe = 0;

        public DataManager data;

            void Start ()

            {
                var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
                var se= new InputField.SubmitEvent();
                se.AddListener(SubmitName);
                input.onEndEdit = se;
            }

        private void SubmitName(string pressure)

            {

            var pressureScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(DataManager)) as DataManager;

            if(int.TryParse(pressure, out intPressure))
            {
                pressureScript.pressure = intPressure;
            }
            else
            {
                // Parse fail, show an error or something
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd indeed have problem with finding out more than one `Component` of same type with `GetComponent<T>`. I would recommend creating GameObject per `InputField`, put it as a child of GameObject holding your `UserInput`.

Then you'd just need to create two public fields that correspond to your `InputField`s, i.e:

```
public InputField field1;
public InputField field2;

//Do something with them
void Start()
{
    DoStuff(field1);
    DoStuff(field2);
}
```

and assign them from inspector. Just drag GameObject holding each `InputField` and drop it on variable inside inspector. That way you'd know exactly which `InputField` you're using. You can also make a prefab from it for reusability and instantiation from code.

Comment: Ok, I will have to look into it.  I was having some issues with having several inputFields.

Comment: I'm afraid you're only allowed to have only one `InputField` attached to certain GameObject. That's true for most if not all of new `Unity3D` UI system components. Nothing stops you from adding GameObjects holding them as children of your script's GameObject. It also encourages keeping clean hierarchy of components in your Unity scene.

Comment: I would think this would have been a much more straight forward, but I guess not.